# showing multiple pushpins on a map in windows phone using mvvm model

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following view in my mvvm model based app which should display all the pushpins I bind to it using binding property "PushPinLocation" from my view model.

```
<MapNS:Map 
    Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,-5,0" 
    CartographicMode="{Binding MapMode, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    LandmarksEnabled="True" PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="True"  
    ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Foreground="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="1" Height="713"  Width="425" 
    x:Name="mapPanoramaAddress"  >

    <!--Adding Location to show map initially until the data arrived-->
    <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>

        <maptk:MapItemsControl Name="StoresMapItemsControl" >
            <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <maptk:Pushpin x:Name="PushPins" Background="White" 
                        GeoCoordinate="{Binding PushPinLocation}" 
                        Content="{Binding PushPinDisplayText}" 
                        Visibility="Visible" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </maptk:MapItemsControl>                                
        <maptk:UserLocationMarker GeoCoordinate="{Binding PushPinLocation}" x:Name="UserLocationMarker" Visibility="Visible" />

    </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>

</MapNS:Map>
```

In the geolocator positionchanged event which triggers for every few meters I am setting the value for binding property "PushPinLocation" (from my view model) which is common for pushpin and location marker.

```
//PushPinLocation
private GeoCoordinate _PushPinLocation = new GeoCoordinate(40.712923, -74.013292);    //cannot assign null 
public GeoCoordinate PushPinLocation
{
    get { return _PushPinLocation; }
    set
    {
        if (_PushPinLocation != value)
        {
            _PushPinLocation = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PushPinLocation");
        }
    }
}
```

in the same viewmodel geolocator_Position changed event I am setting the pushpinlocation:

```
private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    this.PushPinLocation = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
}
```

But I always see the latest one showing up and old ones are never shown on the map.Is there any way I can retain the old ones as well.

Comment: are you binding to a specific point, or to a collection of points?

Comment: To a specific point with the binding property "PushPinLocation".e.g. this.PushPinLocation = new Geocoordinate(altitude,longitude,latitude)

Comment: If you want to show more than one point on your map you (obviously) need to bind to a collection of points. The moment you change the properties of your model (the PushPinLocation..) it updates the view, that so far is correct. But it's the wrong assumption to expect it to just add a new child element. If you want that behavior you need to have a collection of locations in your data source and bind to that collection so **all of them** get displayed on your map.

Answer (score 2):

This post is a year old, but unanswered, so here is my answer:

Instead of binding to a single `PushPinLocation`, use a collection. In your ViewModel, add this:

```
private List<GeoCoordinate> _pushPinLocations;
public List<GeoCoordinate> PushPinLocations
{
    get { return _pushPinLocations; }
    set
    {
        _pushPinLocations = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PushPinLocations");
    }
}
```

and change your event to:

```
private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    this.PushPinLocations.Add(args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate());
}
```

That will add the new location to the list and as long as its bound to this list of locations, all pins will show.

```
<maptk:MapItemsControl Name="StoresMapItemsControl" >
    <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <maptk:Pushpin x:Name="PushPins" Background="White" 
                GeoCoordinate="{Binding PushPinLocations}" 
                Content="{Binding PushPinDisplayText}" 
                Visibility="Visible" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</maptk:MapItemsControl>
```